# How can I count occurrence of numbers in matrix in fortran?

Tags: matrix, count, fortran

I'm using fortran 90, and I hope to count the number of occurence, when two numbers appears in an array.

```
    flag=0
    q=0
    do k=1,ncolumns
      if (conn(m,k)==i .and. conn(m,k)==l) flag=1
    enddo
    if (flag==1) q=q+1 
    write (*,*) q
```

Here, conn(m,k) is the matrix, made up of m lines and k columns. I want to read the conn(m,k), and count the number of occurrence when both number i and l are included in conn(m,k). I know above code will not work because it prints out only 0, since that if loop have a problem. But I cannot use '.or.' because I want the count when i and l both are included in the conn(m,k). How can I check both number i and l are included in conn?

I modified the code above like

```
    ncolumns=2
    flag=0
    q=0
    do k=1,ncolumns
      !!!if (conn(m,k)==i .and. conn(m,k)==l) flag=1
      if (((conn(m,1)==i).and.(conn(m,2)==l)).or.((conn(m,1)==l).and.(conn(m,2)==i))) flag=1
    enddo
    if (flag==1) q=q+1 
    write (*,*) q
```

This works fine, but as you can see, this code is ridiculous since I need to manually define k, specially when 'ncolumns' is huge number. How can I do this with index?

Likewise, how can I check 2 or more specific numbers are included in the matrix like conn(m,k) in fortran? Thanks.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark First one could be more closer. 'conn' is a matrix, and I want to know how many lines of 'conn' have 2 or more numbers, such as 3 and 12, at the same time. And count its occurrence. For example, if there are 3 lines in conn which have two elements (such as 3 and 12) together, the printed q should be 3.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Second example code's 'ncolumns=2' is just example. Actually, conn is huge matrix. It is 5000 lines x 15 columns matrix, made up of numerous data blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ought to do what you want:

```
  nums = [2,12,-4,99]  ! an array of the numbers you're looking for
  q = 0                ! the count of rows containing all the numbers in nums

  DO ix = 1, SIZE(conn,1)       ! the number of rows in conn
     nmatches = 0               ! the number of elements of nums found in conn(ix,:)
     DO jx = 1, SIZE(nums)
        IF(ANY(conn(ix,:)==nums(jx))) nmatches = nmatches+1    ! figure this out yourself
     END DO
     ! if there are as many matches in this row as there are elements in nums, add 1 to q
     IF(nmatches==SIZE(nums)) q = q+1    
  END DO
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't understand this code.... Where 'matches' coming from, and what is meaning of matches?? There are 'nmatches' and 'matches' but I couldn't figure out meaning of both variables. Also, should I need to make new array of a~d? Can I just directly compare i and l or a and b with the matrix 'conn'?

Comment: `matches` was a mistake, should have been `nums`.  And `nums` is just an array containing the numbers you're looking for.  I've edited that too.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a dummy matrix (dummy_mat) to populate with ones where the values are located in the matrix you are searching (value_mat) and then sum the dummy matrix to get the count (num_entries):

```
    nums = [2,12,-4,99]
    do i=1,size(nums)     ! loop over the values you are looking for  
      dummy_mat = 0 ! zero out dummy matrix that is the same size as your value matrix           
      where (value_mat(:,:) == nums(i))    
        dummy_mat(:,:) = 1
      end where
      num_entries(i) = SUM(dummy_mat)
    end do
```

Answer (score 1):

From the comment "if there are 3 lines in conn which have two elements (such as 3 and 12) together, the printed q should be 3".
You can do this with a single loop if you have Fortran95 (I forget if it is in the 90 spec) or later.
Here is an example:

```
Program Test_Count

  Implicit None

  Real(Kind=8), Dimension(3)   :: nums = (/-2.0_8 , -3.0_8 , -4.0_8/)
  Real(Kind=8), Dimension(4,4) :: test
  Logical, Dimension(4) :: Mask
  Integer :: i,j,NumberOfLines

  ! Fill test
  Do i = 1,4
    Do j = 1,4
      test(i,j) = -4.0_8 + (j -1)
    End Do
  End Do

  ! Count the row that have all the nums in them
  Mask = any(test == nums(1),2)
  Do i = 2,3
    Mask = Mask .and. any(test == num2(i),2)
  End Do
  NumberOfLines = count(Mask)

  Write(*,*) NumberOfLines ! Prints out 4.

End Program Test_Count
```